# How to install AMD Drivers on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, graphics, amd-graphics

I'm beginner on Ubuntu and I have a problem on it. So I downloaded drivers for my graphic card (these one http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx) and I don't know how to install it.

Comment: Did you look at this doc: http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link the steps would be:

1. Download drivers for Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or by searching for and clicking the `Terminal icon`
3. (Optional) 
   Create a separate directory for your AMD driver `.deb` files:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/$USER/AMD_Driver_Packages
   ```
4. Copy all `.deb` package files to the newly - created directory:

   ```
   sudo cp /home/$USER/Download/*.deb /home/$USER/AMD_Driver_Packages
   ```
5. After the files have been successfully copied,
   change the current directory to the same directory:

   ```
   cd /home/$USER/AMD_Driver_Packages
   ```
6. If needed, uninstall any previous versions of the 
   AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary driver. Use the following command to check if there are legacy drivers present on your system:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -l fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
   ```
7. Install the distributor-specific package files on your system using the package manager (dpkg) tool as shown below:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i fglrx-core_14.500-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_12.04.4.deb fglrx_14.500-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_12.04.4.deb fglrx-dev_14.500-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_12.04.4.deb fglrx-amdcccle_14.500-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_12.04.4.deb
   ```

**Note:** Please change `step 7` to your version of Ubuntu, or see link below for more information. Again in `step 4` place the contents of the unzipped or untared files into the said location, from that link I don't know what specific drivers you downloaded but the included link to their documentation should help.

Source:

http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf